# Updating Variables In Unity 5

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

Using the Unity UI, every time you click a button, your score goes up by 60. I have another script which is taking that variable and adding it to another score. But when the program starts, the score is set to 0, so the script is taking the original score, which is 0, instead of constantly updating the variable to match the current score.

```
public static float score = 0;
public float scoreAdd = 0;

public void AddScore() 
{ 
    scoreAdd = 60;
    score = score + scoreAdd; 
}
```

So that part works and I'm adding 60 each time I click the button. But then when I reference the variable in another script it outputs as 0. How do I update the reference every time the score variable changes?

```
public static float newscore = buttonclick.score;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I will convey this correctly but in short your reference to the variable `buttonclick.score` in the second script will only happen on instantiation. Instead move the setting of that variable into the `Update` method so it stays updated from the other class.

```
public float newscore;

void Update()
{
    newscore = buttonclick.score;
}
```